# Execute Perl commands from a specific IP?

Tags: debian, scripting, perl, ipv4

I have a Debian Jessie 8 server with three unique IPv4 IPs. I connect to the server from Windows 7 via Putty. I can open three Putty windows using each of the three IPs. I am trying to execute a Perl script that checks whois information using Perl's `use Net::Whois::Raw` and the system's whois using backticks

```
$domain_info = `whois google.com 2>&1`;
$domain_info2 = whois(google.com);
```

The script is automated and keeps on checking different URLs. The issue is, that because of the call frequency from the three windows I am getting

```
whois limit exceeded - see www.pir.org/whois for details
```

How can I execute the Perl script so that each Putty window will use the public IP I used to login to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to
[http://search.cpan.org/~nalobin/Net-Whois-Raw-2.85/lib/Net/Whois/Raw.pm](http://search.cpan.org/%7Enalobin/Net-Whois-Raw-2.85/lib/Net/Whois/Raw.pm), you can:

> set_ips_for_server('whois.ripn.net', ['127.0.0.1']);
>
> You can specify
> IPs list which will be used for queries to desired whois server. It
> can be useful if you have few interfaces, but you need to access whois
> server from specified ips.

Comment: I added 
`set_ips_for_server('whois.pir.org', ['xxx.xxx.xxx.123']);
set_ips_for_server('whois.verisign-grs.com', [''xxx.xxx.xxx.124']);
set_ips_for_server('whois.verisign-grs.com', ['xxx.xxx.xxx.125']);`

and now I get `Undefined subroutine &main::set_ips_for_server called at myScript.pl line 9.`

Comment: Looks like the function is not exported; try prefixing the call -- Net::Whois::Raw::set_ips_for_server(....)

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul did you get it working?

Comment: Your suggestion worked. It seems to have forced the whois to be executed from the IPs I set, but I still wonder, how can you make the whole script be seen via a set IP?

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to pass that IP in as a parameter, then.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `pwhois` utility of that module at https://api.metacpan.org/source/NALOBIN/Net-Whois-Raw-2.85/pwhois indicates there is a `-a srcip` flag, though you're calling `whois` which may or may not be `pwhois`.